# How replace cutting string logic with Regex?

Tags: java, regex, refactoring

I want to replace my clumsy logic to regex solution. My solution works but it is very redundant.

I have to process **JSON** data:

> {"action":"stop"}

and take as a result only - `stop`.

Here is my solution:

```
private String processAction(String actionJson) {     
    String[] data = actionJson.split(":");
    int limit = data[1].length() - 3;
    String result = data[1].substring(1, limit);
    return result;
}
```

I am wondering to know how to solve this task with Regex.

***How to refactor this logic with regex solution?***

Comment: @markspace Good suggestion. I will check it. But **Regex solution** is interesting for me too.

Comment: Regex is not a solution for parsing JSON because JSON is not a regular language. As @markspace says, use a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're dealing with JSON data in the format of:

```
{"something1":"something2"}
```

And you're always wanting `something2`

Here's a simple one line non `regex` way and a `regex` way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(processAction("{\"action\":\"stop\"}"));
    System.out.println(processActionRegex("{\"action\":\"go\"}"));
}

private static String processAction(String actionJson) {     
    return actionJson.substring(actionJson.indexOf(":\"") + 2, actionJson.lastIndexOf("\""));
}

private static String processActionRegex(String actionJson) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\"(\\w+)\":\"(\\w+)\"\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(actionJson);

    String result = "";
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        result = matcher.group(2);
    } else {
        // Throw exception?
    }

    return result;
}
```

Results:

```
stop
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Something a bit more dynamic could be like:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\":\"([^\"]+)\"")
    .matcher(actionJson);

while (m.find()) {
    if ("action".equals(m.group(1)))
        return m.group(2);
}

throw new IllegalArgumentException("no action found");
```

This simply loops through all the key-value pairs and returns the value whose key is `action`.

`\"([^\"]+)\"` captures a non-empty group of quoted characters:

```
\"          // begin quote
(           // begin capture group
    [^\"]+  // 1 or more characters which are not a quote
)           // end capture group
\"          // end quote
```

If the only key is `action`, then you don't need a loop.

As already pointed out in a comment, using a JSON parser is the best because they are prepared to deal with any funny business. For example, the regular expression I used above doesn't handle whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
String subStr = str.replaceAll("(?ius)\\{\".*?\":\"(.*?)\"\\}", "$1");
System.out.println(subStr);
```

This works for me